# Find value of visible rows in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm able to get the correct row count, but the problem is when I run through the loop.

```
OrdNum = dgvWsNorth.Rows(i).Cells("ORDNUM").Value.ToString()
```

This line will loop through all visible and non visible rows = to the row count.

I need it to loop through only the visible rows = to the row count.

```
Dim AllRows As Integer = dgvWsNorth.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
        Dim OrdNum As Integer
        Dim LinNum As Integer
        Dim UnitPriority As Integer
        Dim Ws_N As Integer = My.Settings.NorthLine

        For i = 0 To AllRows - 1

            OrdNum = dgvWsNorth.Rows(i).Cells("ORDNUM").Value.ToString()
            LinNum = dgvWsNorth.Rows(i).Cells("LINE").Value.ToString()


            If IsDBNull(dgvWsNorth.Rows(i).Cells("UNIT_PRIORITY").Value) Then
                UnitPriority = 999
            Else
                UnitPriority = dgvWsNorth.Rows(i).Cells("UNIT_PRIORITY").Value.ToString()
            End If

                clsScheduler.UPDATE_ASSIGNED_WS(Ws_N, OrdNum, LinNum, clsLogin.plant_id, clsLogin.dept_id, UnitPriority)

        Next
```

Comment: Just because the rows are hidden doesn't mean their row index changes. As already answered, I think you will need to check if the current iteration is a visible row or not and act on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping through all rows, and only counting the rows that are visible?

```
    Dim i = 0
    Dim OrdNum As Integer
    Dim LinNum As Integer
    Dim UnitPriority As Integer
    Dim Ws_N As Integer = My.Settings.NorthLine
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvWsNorth.Rows

        If r.Visible Then

            OrdNum = r.Cells("ORDNUM").Value.ToString()
            LinNum = r.Cells("LINE").Value.ToString()


            If IsDBNull(r.Cells("UNIT_PRIORITY").Value) Then
                UnitPriority = 999
            Else
                UnitPriority = r.Cells("UNIT_PRIORITY").Value.ToString()
            End If

            clsScheduler.UPDATE_ASSIGNED_WS(Ws_N, OrdNum, LinNum, clsLogin.plant_id, clsLogin.dept_id, UnitPriority)

            i += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I decided to give this a shot and I think you can do this with a Lambda on your for each statement

Instead of a for next loop use a for each with a lambda expression

```
For each r as datagridviewrow in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of Datagridviewrow)().Where(Function(row) row.Visible = true)

... your loop code using r instead of rows(i)

Next
```

This should only iterate through rows that are visible.